# Transactions across microservices with Seneca

Tags: node.js, database, microservices

I'm start to develop a web application in microservice architecture with SenecaJS framework.
It has good documentation but I don't understand if I can solve the problem of "transaction across microservices" with it or I should implement something by myself.

Have you a suggestions?

Comment: Whats an example of your architecture or what the services you're referring to are? If you're not keeping track of state in your services such that they're idempotent, you probably don't have to worry about transactions.